# Detect and alert remote Management screen-sharing

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm trying to make a script to sent an alert when screen sharing is on.

The following command is supposed to list every established VNC connection but this doesn't return anything at all for me :

```
netstat -a | grep vnc | grep ESTABLISHED
```

the only option I found to list past connection :

```
 log show --predicate 'processImagePath CONTAINS "screensharingd" AND
 eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication"'
```

Any idea how to get current VNC session ? and even better, any idea how to sent an alert/email in the background each time a new connection is done

PS : just to make sure, Apple Screen-Sharing (from remote management) is using VNC protocol right?

Comment: this guy says this works -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552312/how-to-detect-when-os-x-screen-sharing-is-active-programmatically:
lsof -a -i :vnc-server -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -c AppleVNCServer

Comment: How have you configured privacy settings and sharing settings? There are quite a few ways this data can leave macOS. Not all are VNC.